# How to define a highly scalable folder structure for your Angular 6 project?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am just learning more about angular 6 and its core features ,  I am confused a little bit about which folder structure I should USE for angular 6 ,  I have used different structures from different tutorials eg traversymedia, udemy and list goes on, everyone uses different folder structure depending on the project.

here is basic folder structure from angular docs
[image]

here is what I have tried after searching and searchning

```
└───src
    ├───app
    │   ├───layout
    │   │   ├───admin
    │   │   │   ├───breadcrumbs
    │   │   │   └───title
    │   │   └───auth
    │   ├───pages
    │   │   ├───animations
    │   │   ├───authentication
    │   │   │   ├───forgot
    │   │   │   ├───lock-screen
    │   │   │   ├───login
    │   │   │   │   ├───with-bg-image
    │   │   │   │   ├───with-header-footer
    │   │   │   │   ├───with-social
    │   │   │   │   └───with-social-header-footer
    │   │   │   └───registration
    │   │   │       ├───multi-step
    │   │   │       ├───with-bg-image
    │   │   │       ├───with-header-footer
    │   │   │       ├───with-social
    │   │   │       └───with-social-header-footer
    │   │   ├───change-log
    │   │   ├───charts
    │   │   │   ├───c3-js
    │   │   │   ├───chart-js
    │   │   │   ├───echart
    │   │   │   ├───google
    │   │   │   ├───knob
    │   │   │   ├───peity
    │   │   │   ├───radial
    │   │   │   └───sparklines
    │   │   ├───dashboard
    │   │   │   ├───dashboard-analytics
    │   │   │   ├───dashboard-crm
    │   │   │   ├───dashboard-default
    │   │   │   ├───dashboard-ecommerce
    │   │   │   └───dashboard-project
    │   │   ├───invoice
    │   │   │   ├───basic-invoice
    │   │   │   ├───list-invoice
    │   │   │   └───summary-invoice
    │   │   ├───maintenance
    │   │   │   ├───coming-soon
    │   │   │   ├───error
    │   │   │   └───offline-ui
    │   │   ├───map
    │   │   │   ├───google-map
    │   │   │   └───vector
    │   │   ├───simple-page
    │   │   ├───task
    │   │   │   ├───board-task
    │   │   │   ├───details-task
    │   │   │   ├───issue-task
    │   │   │   └───list-task
    │   │   ├───ui-elements
    │   │   │   ├───advance
    │   │   │   │   ├───modal
    │   │   │   │   ├───notifications
    │   │   │   │   └───notify
    │   │   │   ├───basic
    │   │   │   │   ├───accordion
    │   │   │   │   ├───alert
    │   │   │   │   ├───breadcrumb
    │   │   │   │   ├───button
    │   │   │   │   ├───generic-class
    │   │   │   │   ├───label-badge
    │   │   │   │   ├───tabs
    │   │   │   │   ├───typography
    │   │   │   │   └───ui-other
    │   │   │   ├───crm-contact
    │   │   │   ├───editor
    │   │   │   │   ├───froala-edit
    │   │   │   │   └───quill-edit
    │   │   │   ├───file-upload
    │   │   │   ├───forms
    │   │   │   │   ├───add-on
    │   │   │   │   ├───advance-elements
    │   │   │   │   ├───basic-elements
    │   │   │   │   ├───form-validation
    │   │   │   │   ├───masking
    │   │   │   │   ├───picker
    │   │   │   │   └───select
    │   │   │   └───tables
    │   │   │       ├───bootstrap-table
    │   │   │       │   ├───basic-bootstrap
    │   │   │       │   ├───border
    │   │   │       │   ├───sizing
    │   │   │       │   └───styling
    │   │   │       └───data-table
    │   │   │           ├───basic-datatable
    │   │   │           ├───child-row
    │   │   │           ├───inline-edit
    │   │   │           ├───other-datatable
    │   │   │           ├───paging
    │   │   │           └───selection
    │   │   │               ├───cell
    │   │   │               ├───checkbox
    │   │   │               ├───multi-rows
    │   │   │               └───single-row
    │   │   ├───user
    │   │   │   ├───card
    │   │   │   └───profile
    │   │   └───widget
    │   │       ├───widget-advance
    │   │       ├───widget-chart
    │   │       ├───widget-data
    │   │       └───widget-static
    │   └───shared
    │       ├───accordion
    │       ├───card
    │       ├───element
    │       ├───fullscreen
    │       ├───menu-items
    │       ├───modal-animation
    │       ├───modal-basic
    │       ├───scroll
    │       └───spinner
    │           └───spinkit-css
    ├───assets
    │   ├───charts
    │   │   ├───amchart
    │   │   ├───echart
    │   │   ├───flot
    │   │   ├───knob
    │   │   ├───radial
    │   │   └───waterball
    │   ├───css
    │   ├───data
    │   ├───icon
    │   │   ├───icofont
    │   │   │   ├───css
    │   │   │   └───fonts
    │   │   └───svg-animated
    │   ├───images
    │   │   ├───auth
    │   │   ├───commingsoon
    │   │   ├───error
    │   │   ├───flags
    │   │   ├───mega-menu
    │   │   ├───modal
    │   │   ├───slider
    │   │   ├───task
    │   │   ├───tooltip
    │   │   ├───user-card
    │   │   │   └───card
    │   │   ├───user-profile
    │   │   │   └───follower
    │   │   └───widget
    │   ├───jq-vmap
    │   │   └───maps
    │   │       └───continents
    │   └───pages
    │       └───treeview
    └───environments
```

Which type I should use for real world application sample from angular or the one I designed myself? please share your structure if you think its much better than what I have. thanks

Comment: I'd advise you to definitely avoid a custom structure. I like the `core/shared/feature` pattern. You can have a look here for a quick overview : https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/6-best-practices-pro-tips-for-angular-cli-better-developer-experience-7b328bc9db81

Comment: This is wholly opinion based, and therefore a bad question for SO. It's also not something you're stuck with; you can move folders around later if you change your mind.

Comment: It takes experience to pick a structure. My structure won't work for you. Start with what works now. As your project grows change it. Don't overthink it and avoid complexity until you can't avoid it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I am using below folder structure for the angular highly scalable applications. The below folder structure is created based on best practices from the community, other GitHub Angular projects and my own experiences from working on a couple of Angular projects.

```
|-- app

     |-- [+] configs
     |
     |
     |-- core
       |-- [+] authentication
       |-- [+] guards
       |-- [+] http
       |-- [+] interceptors
       |-- [+] layout
       |-- [+] mocks
       |-- [+] services
       |-- [+] strategies
       |-- core.module.ts
       |-- router.animations.ts
       |-- template-core.module.ts
       |-- theme.module.ts
       |-- ensureModuleLoadedOnceGuard.ts
       |-- logger.service.ts    
     |
     |     
     |-- modules
       |-- client
           |-- [+] components
           |-- client-routing.module.ts
           |-- client.module.ts
       |--- [+] other modules

     |
     |-- shared
          |-- [+] components
          |-- [+] directives
          |-- [+] pipes
          |-- [+] models
          |-- [+] module
      |
      |-- app-routing.module.ts
      |-- app.module.ts
      |-- etc ...
      |
|-- assets
     |-- images
     |-- icons
     |-- css
          |-- styles.scss
```

I have created the GitHub high-level angular demo project "[angular6-realworld-highly-scalable-application](https://github.com/rajaramtt/angular6-realworld-highly-scalable-application)" for future reference.

Github Link: https://github.com/rajaramtt/angular6-realworld-highly-scalable-application

One of the useful Medium  Reference link: https://itnext.io/choosing-a-highly-scalable-folder-structure-in-angular-d987de65ec7

Comment: why are "services" in core but "models" in shared? I would intuitively place them in the same folder.

Comment: @DanielMethner   To my certain knowledge, The Core Module should contain singleton services, and shared models used across the application

Comment: Hi correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the usage of `CoreModule` removed as raised in [this Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17825) and it's following [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/28434)? The inclusion of `providedIn: 'root'` property for `@Injectable` directive in Angular 5 had make the necessity for a CoreModule redundant. Personally, I declare "Core" components in `AppModule` as I don't see a direct distinction between a "Core" and "Root" module.